# Parsing data then mapping from JSON using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

As a beginner to React, I have been struggling with this issue for a couple days now and any direction is appreciated. I am able to console log my JSON result from my API but I cannot get the data to display in my component. I want to map the data to the component. I have individual sections for each data entry from my JSON.

My App.js is:

```
fetch("MY_URL", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  airData.setState({
    content: data 
  })
});



class App extends Component {
  
  render () {
        
        return (
          <div className="app">
            <Header />
            <div className="spacer"></div>
            <OverallStatus />
              {airData.map(data=>{
                return (
                  <div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconHumidity} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Humidity {data.humidity}%</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.humidity}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconAirPressure} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Air Pressure {data.AirPressure} hPa</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.AirPressure}
                      maxCompleted={1030} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Dioxide {data.CO2} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO2}
                      maxCompleted={2000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconVOCs} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />VOCs {data.TVOC} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.TVOC}
                      maxCompleted={1000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconParticulateMatter} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Particulate Matter 2.5 {data.PM25} ug/m3</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.PM25}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonMonoxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Monoxide {data.CO} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconNitrogenDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Nitrogen Dioxide {data.NO2} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.NO2}
                      maxCompleted={200} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconOzone} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Ozone {data.Ozone} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.Ozone}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
              );})}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
  
  

export default App;
```

Comment: what is airData.setState?? are you using func or class component?

Comment: @NileshPatel I am using Class component. Where airData is is where I had my console logging the JSON data. I just don’t know how to pull it from there and map into the component.

Comment: is the fetch call really outside of the class component and where is the declaration of airData

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling you're mixing state lifecycles with hooks. If you want to use state, such as setState, you'll need to initialize it in the constructor and reference it with this. [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) you don't.

Here are some great examples: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      brand: "Ford",
      model: "Mustang",
      color: "red",
      year: 1964
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My {this.state.brand}</h1>
        <p>
          It is a {this.state.color}
          {this.state.model}
          from {this.state.year}.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It is great to learn the full lifecycle, but you'll find hooks much easier later on.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried putting the fetch call inside of the App component. The component prolly doesnt update (not sure) because it doesnt know the state has changed. Since AirData is outside.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {content: undefined}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("MY_URL", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data)
         this.setState({})
         this.setState({
          content: data 
         })
});
  }
  
  render () {
        
        return (
          <div className="app">
            <Header />
            <div className="spacer"></div>
            <OverallStatus />
              {this.state.content?.map(data=>{
                return (
                  <div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconHumidity} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Humidity {data.humidity}%</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.humidity}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconAirPressure} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Air Pressure {data.AirPressure} hPa</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.AirPressure}
                      maxCompleted={1030} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Dioxide {data.CO2} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO2}
                      maxCompleted={2000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconVOCs} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />VOCs {data.TVOC} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.TVOC}
                      maxCompleted={1000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconParticulateMatter} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Particulate Matter 2.5 {data.PM25} ug/m3</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.PM25}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonMonoxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Monoxide {data.CO} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconNitrogenDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Nitrogen Dioxide {data.NO2} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.NO2}
                      maxCompleted={200} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconOzone} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Ozone {data.Ozone} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.Ozone}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
              );})}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: This seems to have got close but I keep on receiving ```App.js:59 Uncaught TypeError```

Comment: can you update the question or could you provide your code somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to define state, and make use of life cycle hook to perform side-effect.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      airData = [];
    }
  }

componentDidMount(){
 fetch("MY_URL", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({
      airData: data 
    })
  });
 }

  render () {
        
        return (
          <div className="app">
            <Header />
            <div className="spacer"></div>
            <OverallStatus />
              {airData.map(data=>{
                return (
                  <div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconHumidity} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Humidity {data.humidity}%</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.humidity}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconAirPressure} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Air Pressure {data.AirPressure} hPa</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.AirPressure}
                      maxCompleted={1030} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Dioxide {data.CO2} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO2}
                      maxCompleted={2000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconVOCs} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />VOCs {data.TVOC} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.TVOC}
                      maxCompleted={1000} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconParticulateMatter} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Particulate Matter 2.5 {data.PM25} ug/m3</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.PM25}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconCarbonMonoxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Carbon Monoxide {data.CO} ppm</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.CO}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconNitrogenDioxide} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Nitrogen Dioxide {data.NO2} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.NO2}
                      maxCompleted={200} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='qualityFactor'>
                      <h1><img src={iconOzone} alt="Logo" className="iconSmall" />Ozone {data.Ozone} ppb</h1>
                      <ProgressBar completed={data.Ozone}
                      maxCompleted={100} className="statusBar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
              );})}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
  
  

export default App;
```